# Loadrunner replay error

Tags: correlation, loadrunner, wicketstuff

I am recoriding a script on a web/http protocoll, but when replying I get errors on

Recording the script twice and checking for diffs manually I found that my URLs has some "listeners" in them like:

```
web_submit_data("bla_bla_2", 

            "Action=http://e34jbsl00267.somesone.se:8080/xxx/xxx/81174/xxx?5-1.IBehaviorListener.0-considerSomeList-considerSomeRepeater-4-considerSomeListItem-considerSomeMain-innerPanel-considerDetails-considerForm-considerRulesChoices",
            "Method=POST",
```

When removing everything from the end at the url down to 'xxx?5-' the script is replaying fine, but when having these listeneres there it wont work with 500 error, and pasting in the url above in a new browser gives me a error page generated from the app.

This smells like correlation, but I cannot see these listenres being returned by the server, so correlation is not possible as I know it.

Help?

BR
fugmag

Comment: and using ajaxtruclient made it possible to replay the script. maybe truclient was developed for these kind of rich internet apps...

Comment: solved. follow this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780394/loadrunner-scripting-java-or-c-inside-a-vuser-script-to-manipulate-a-web-app-in

Comment: the issue continous here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780394/loadrunner-scripting-java-or-c-inside-a-vuser-script-to-manipulate-a-web-app-in

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record it twice and compare the recordings.   IF different then this will confirm the correlation hypothesis.   Typically when a 500 occurs, barring a malformed request, it is simply out of context with the state of the application from the prior request, an unexpected page has been returned.

You may cross check for the unexpected page by following standard test practices, for each and every step there is an expected result.   Use web_reg_find() or web_reg_save_param() to check for values from each submitted page request which indicates that the expected page has been returned.   If the expected page has not been returned then break the flow of the business process script, clean up and then either return to the business flow or move to the next iteration. ( return(1); will cause the system to iterate immediately without respecting the iteration pacing )

Comment: Ok James. The results are different, but this is a so called rich internet app as in web 2.0 with i.e. clicking some elements would change the "looks" of the page, as in one click leads to a radiobutton collection appearing and so forth. I guess TruClient is developed to cope with such things and replay works using TruClient. also I tried to remove the "isteners" in the above code chunk and it did work, but the radiobutton Collection did not appear in the Viewer during replay indicating that removing them led to the pageelements not being displayd.

Comment: The replay browser is not full featured, so consider the log as authoritative.   As you have dynamic elements in play then it seems likely that you will need to correlate elements on the line.   And yes, TruClient is the route for True asynchronous apps.   It is possible to have the JaX components (without the A) and still have a synchronous HTML business process.

Comment: ok, what do you meen with "correlate elements on the line", James?

Comment: So it is possible to use http protocol with Ajax pages, I take it you mean? Could you please give me an example of correlating elementa on the line?

Comment: Correlation would take an understanding of the entire script and would be outside of the context of peer support here.   I generally record three times.  Twice with same credentials and data and a third with different credentials and data.   This ensures that I can Identify everything with session, state, time and business process

Comment: I will post the entire script on Monday, but as we talked about a few miutes ago, I might close this one, because I have a more spesific approach to the Challenge ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780394/loadrunner-scripting-java-or-c-inside-a-vuser-script-to-manipulate-a-web-app-in